# How to add a point under the link

Tags: html, css

Pretty simple question, I want add a point, under the link... how can I do it? I think it would be with css.

For example;
[Click](https://i.hizliresim.com/nbaV00.jpg)

Comment: Do you have access to the full source code? Can you please share some code sample? A DOM-manipulation may be required, which requires knowledge about the available element attributes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please add a "Minimal, Reproducible Example" of your code to this question, Please take a moment to visit the Help Center and specifically the section on 'Asking' for more details >>> stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used an after pseudo-element and positioned it relative to the containing element.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

li.active::after {
  content: "•";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>About</li>
  <li class="active">Files</li>
  <li>Chat</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks your respond. That's exactly what wanted. This is working on Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but this is not working on Safari. A situation caused by content attribute.  Works on all browsers when  update content attribute : `content: '\2022';`